# Three js: Enlarging raycaster area

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using raycaster to determine what objects the mouse is hovering over. With Lines, there's a linePrecision (which I think is set to 1 by default). So when the mouse gets close to a line without to be exactly on the line, the raycaster returns the object. However, with shapes/meshes, the mouse has to be very precise with this. It has to be inside of the shape/mesh before raycaster detects the intersection (therefore returning the object).

To be even more specific, I have text rendered in three.js as shapes and I'm trying to make them hoverable/selectable. If I use a font that's too light weight (opposite of bold), the mouse has to be exactly inside the font before it's detected (i.e. if mouse is in the hole of an "o" character, raycaster doesn't detect the text as hovered). Text selection is therefore frustrating for the user.

Is there a way to get the same effects I get with raycaster vs lines (detects intersection if mouse is close) but for raycaster vs shapes/mesh?

I've tried adjusting raycaster.linePrecision and it didn't work.

Comment: Sadly, the [Raycaster class](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster) doesn't have that property you're looking for. However, you could alleviate your precision problem by placing a plane in front of your text with `opacity: 0` and use it as a "hit area" to check for raycaster intersection.

Comment: Thanks @Marquizzo. I was thinking about that but I didn't want to create unnecessary objects if I didn't have to. Looks like I'll just have to do that if no one else can think of a better solution.